# Indexing using SQL Data Table

Tags: sql, indexing, user-input

I've created a database that will function as a list of seasonal fruit/veg. I need to search that database, using user input, and then, append it to an empty list, and then append the price value from that input, and append that to the second empty list. But, when I run the program it reads an IndexError: list index is out of range.

What I need to do after, is ask the user to input how many KGs they want of the item they've selected and times it by the price (that I should get from indexing).

```py
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('seasonalProduce.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS productList (
        productID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        productName text NOT NULL,
        productPrice real
);""")



#add rows (records) to the productList table

productRecords = [(1, "Apples", 4.59),
                (2, "Grapes", 5.99),
                (3, "Pumpkin", 3.00),
                (4, "Strawberries", 2.50),
                (5, "Leafy Greens", 4.00)]
        
cursor.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO productList (productID, productName, productPrice) VALUES(?,?,?);", productRecords)

connection.commit()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM productList;")

produce = cursor.fetchall()

for rows in produce:
    print(rows)

connection.close()
# create list to store productID("ID"), price("price")
#with empty list as their values
#data structure to hold user items as they make their order
groceryList = []
priceList = []

total = 0
productType = 0 

#create tuples list with products
productsList = [(1, "Apples", 4.59),
                (2, "Grapes", 5.99),
                (3, "Pumpkin", 3.00),
                (4, "Strawberries", 2.50),
                (5, "Leafy Greens", 4.00)]

# This loop terminates when user select 2.EXIT option when asked
# in try it will ask user for an option as an integer (1 or 2) 
# if correct then proceed with an if/else statement asking for user input

# It should continue and keep adding the total price * weight - BUT THIS FUNCTION DOESN'T WORK

while True: 
    try:
        choice = int(input("1.SELECT\n2.EXIT\nPlease select 1 or 2 (from the menu) here : ")) #use new line formatting
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid response. Please try again.")
    #
    if choice == 1:
        #have user enter productID -unique identification for each product
        #
        #straight into inner-loop with validation
        while True: #create inner loop to search database
            connection = sqlite3.connect('seasonalProduce.db')  #sQ search database
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            itemID = int(input("Please enter the product ID here : "))
            #
            #To display the updates animals to screen:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM productList WHERE productID = ?;", (itemID,))
            #
            results = cursor.fetchall() #if it's there returns single row - list with 1 tuple
            #
            if results == []:
                print("Product ID not found.")
            else:
                #if it does exist return rows
                print(results) 
                #append to groceryList[]
                groceryList.append((results))
                #access price with indexing [2]
                priceList.append((results[2]))
                #
                #print(priceList)
                #Close connection to database
                connection.close()
                break
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `results` is a list of *rows*, therefore `results[2]` is trying to find the 3rd row, which does not exist. What you want is `results[0][2]`, which is the third column of the first row.

I fixed a few more bugs in your code (except for the original error) that prevented us from running it. Next time, check that your code run before asking for help.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll compare the changes now. Still learning.

Comment: Thanks Emilio, the code still doesn't run though. There's likely an error with indenting. I'm working on it again now.